# Running gradle task taking forever

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to run my app using flutter run command but it's not completing its now two hours

```
$ flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device AOSP on IA Emulator. If you get
graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembly debug'...                                  
(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)
```

Comment: Can you attach the output of `flutter doctor`

Comment: flutter doctor doesnt give any error

Comment: Can you attach the output?